# Parameter @BranchName has no default value

Tags: c#

I'm trying to develop inventory control system for computer department of my office. It will keep track of ins and outs of machines from branches which are send to Head Office for repair. I'll also use crystal report to display all the records from Microsoft Access 2010. I have this error message box pops up when I click on save button of entry form.

(Parameter @BranchName has no default value)

I use Microsoft Access 2010, C#.NET with VS 2010. Please help me.

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\NLA\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\GlobalTreasureBank\GlobalTreasureBank\GTBDB.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=admin@GTB");
                try
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                    command.Connection=connect;
                    command.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Machine (BranchName, MachineName, ArrivedDate, FaultDetail, ReturnDate, Remark, Technician)" + "VALUES (@BranchName, @MachineName, @ArrivedDate, @FaultDetail, @ReturnDate, @Remark, @Technician)";

                    string BranchName = txtbBranch.Text;
                    string MachineName = txtbMachine.Text;
                    string FaultDetail = rtxtbFault.Text;
                    string Remark = rtxtbRemark.Text;
                    string Technician = txtbTechnician.Text;
                    DateTime ArrivedDate = dtpArrive.Value;
                    DateTime ReturnDate = dtpReturn.Value;

                    command.Parameters.Add("ArrivedDate", OleDbType.Date);
                    command.Parameters.Add("ReturnDate", OleDbType.Date);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", txtbBranch.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineName", txtbMachine.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultDetail", rtxtbFault.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", rtxtbRemark.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technician", txtbTechnician.Text);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate", dtpArrive.Value);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", dtpReturn.Value);

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show ("Successfully write to database", "Write to Database", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    connect.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    connect.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `txtbBranch.Text` value and what is the type of your `BranchName` column? What is your query looks like when you debug it?

Comment: can't you check if the value is not exist then dont add the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note 1 :** `OleDB` doesnot accept the `named parameters`.
**Note 2 :** `OleDB` Parameters need tobe in sequential order.

Try This:

```
command.CommandText= "INSERT INTO Machine (BranchName, MachineName, ArrivedDate, 
   FaultDetail, ReturnDate, Remark, Technician) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchName", txtbBranch.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MachineName", txtbMachine.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ArrivedDate", dtpArrive.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FaultDetail", rtxtbFault.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReturnDate", dtpReturn.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remark", rtxtbRemark.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Technician", txtbTechnician.Text);
```

Comment: Parameter ?_1 has no default value

Comment: @NayLynnAung: please debug and check wether each variable has value or not.

Comment: As you can see in my code, I declared 7 variables. They are empty now. They have no values. They will have their value after I type in some things in text boxes or date time pickers

Comment: As a matter of fact, I'm just beginner in programming. Please teach me how to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: @NayLynnAung: can you debug and see those textbox feild values ?